# FPS в браузере

Tags: javascript

Надо посчитать фпс в браузере (допустим по этому алгоритму http://jsfiddle.net/vZP3u/). Искажается ли результат из-за отрисовки и просчета этого в канвасе? Если да, то каким образом записывать данные, чтобы потом или в процессе можно было показывать реальное изменение фпс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас вы считаете FPS в canvas. Если вам нужно посчитать FPS при работе c HTML/CSS, то это возможно только через DevTool -- http://www.rubaxa.org/screenshot/4cefd9ab7279916b81b0a48151c7.png, так же DevTool/Timeline.

P.S. Подобный инструмент есть ещё в IE11 и Opera (вроде).

**UPD**: Упс, неверно прочел вопрос. Всё правильно вы сделали, на процесс это не сильно будет влиять.

Comment: а вообще без искажений не реально хранить историю фпс?

Comment: А зачем вам история? Можно хранить минимальную, максимальную и среднюю.

Comment: если спрашиваю, значит надо) так возможно или нет?

Comment: Возможно, просто пишите значения в массив, только боюсь такой массив съест всю память :]

Comment: а то что будет память жрать не повлияет на результаты?

Comment: @Виталий Леонов есть такой закон - измерение динамического процесса влияет на сам процесс, причем он вплоть до квантовой физики. так-что совсем не повлиять не получится :)